# Faceting using SolrJ and Solr4

Tags: java, solr, solrj, faceted-search, solr4

I've gone through the related questions on this site but haven't found a relevant solution.

When querying my Solr4 index using an HTTP request of the form

```
&facet=true&facet.field=country
```

The response contains all the different countries along with counts per country.

How can I get this information using SolrJ?
I have tried the following but it only returns total counts across all countries, not per country:

```
solrQuery.setFacet(true);
solrQuery.addFacetField("country");
```

The following does seem to work, but I do not want to have to explicitly set all the groupings beforehand:

```
solrQuery.addFacetQuery("country:usa");
solrQuery.addFacetQuery("country:canada");
```

Secondly, I'm not sure how to extract the facet data from the QueryResponse object.

So two questions:

1) Using SolrJ how can I facet on a field and return the groupings without explicitly specifying the groups?

2) Using SolrJ how can I extract the facet data from the QueryResponse object?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I also tried something similar to Sergey's response (below).

```
List<FacetField> ffList = resp.getFacetFields();
log.info("size of ffList:" + ffList.size());
for(FacetField ff : ffList){
    String ffname = ff.getName();
    int ffcount = ff.getValueCount();
    log.info("ffname:" + ffname + "|ffcount:" + ffcount);           
}
```

The above code shows ffList with size=1 and the loop goes through 1 iteration. In the output ffname="country" and ffcount is the total number of rows that match the original query.

There is no per-country breakdown here.

I should mention that on the same solrQuery object I am also calling addField and addFilterQuery. Not sure if this impacts faceting:

```
solrQuery.addField("user-name");
solrQuery.addField("user-bio");
solrQuery.addField("country");
solrQuery.addFilterQuery("user-bio:" + "(Apple OR Google OR Facebook)");
```

**Update 2:**

I think I got it, again based on what Sergey said below. I extracted the List object using FacetField.getValues().

```
List<FacetField> fflist = resp.getFacetFields();
for(FacetField ff : fflist){
    String ffname = ff.getName();
    int ffcount = ff.getValueCount();
    List<Count> counts = ff.getValues();
    for(Count c : counts){
        String facetLabel = c.getName();
        long facetCount = c.getCount();
    }
}
```

In the above code the label variable matches each facet group and count is the corresponding count for that grouping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you need only to set facet field and facet will be activated (check SolrJ source code):

```
solrQuery.addFacetField("country");
```

Where did you look for facet information? It must be in `QueryResponse.getFacetFields` (`getValues.getCount`)

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I updated my question above to include the approach you mention.

Answer (score 2):

In the solr Response  you should use `QueryResponse.getFacetFields()` to get `List` of `FacetFields` among which figure "country". so "country" is  idenditfied by `QueryResponse.getFacetFields().get(0)`

you iterate then over it to get `List` of `Count` objects using

```
QueryResponse.getFacetFields().get(0).getValues().get(i)
```

and get value name of facet using `QueryResponse.getFacetFields().get(0).getValues().get(i).getName()`
and the corresponding weight using

```
QueryResponse.getFacetFields().get(0).getValues().get(i).getCount()
```