# SOLR distinct query

Tags: java, solr

i have to select distinct values from a specific field in solr using Java. I have applied

```
        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
        solrQuery.add("q", "*:*");
        solrQuery.setParam("fl", "field_name");
        solrQuery.add("facet", "on");
        solrQuery.add("facet.field_name", "field_name");
```

And i have tried very diffrent methods but still don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faceting using SolrJ and Solr4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485031/faceting-using-solrj-and-solr4)

Answer (score 1):

"facet.field_name" has to be "facet.field". A little less error prone is

```
query.setFacet(true);
query.addFacetField("field_name");
```

Comment: for ngram fields it is returning all the substrings, how to get unique values in that case?

Answer (score 0):

SolrJ has convinient methods to achieve this.

```
solrQuery.setQuery("your query field","value");
solrQuery.setFacet(true);
solrQuery.addFacetField("your specific field for distincts");
solrQuery.setRows(0);
```

Once you hit the server with this request, you can get the unique field values as a
 List of FacetField objects from the QueryResponse object.

I have set **solrQuery.setRows(0);** to avoid query responses and make it more efficient. This doesn't affect the facet results.